# Double image on product save while adding a new imge

Tags: magento-enterprise, product-images, image-upload

I am adding an image with product, so after uploading image and save button there is a problem. The image which I uploaded has saved but one extra row has been created.

After inspecting the element I found that following thing:
 - First row have image which I was uploading.
 - Second row trying to show an image with the name `my_image_1.jpg`

So magento try to upload same image two time but not successfully.

Does any one have any idea why it is happening and where should I look?

Comment: Which version your are using and which browser ?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.14.1.0, Chrome :- Version 44.0.2403.125 (64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried with different browser?

Comment: Yes it exist in all browsers